# Yii Unit testing and captcha

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, yii, captcha

Anybody knows how to avoid captcha within Unit testing (Selenium) with Yii 1.x ?
I've tried to get cuurent captcha value using in my tests:

```
$vc_key = "Yii.CCaptchaAction." . Yii::app()->getId() . ".site.captcha";
$captchaCode = Yii::app()->session->get($vc_key);
```

- got empty value. Also have tried with:

```
$captcha=Yii::app()->getController()->createAction("captcha");
$captchaCode = $captcha->verifyCode;
```

And got an error: **Fatal error:  Call to a member function createAction() on a non-object**

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA#Solving_CAPTCHA

Comment: Why downvote? Please leave comment. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this way:
1. Add to your test config (it uses by Yii unit tests) some variable lets say, it will be "testmode":

```
...
'params' => array(
    'testmode' => true, // to avoid captcha validation
),
...
```

2. In your model validation rules set corresponding condition. For me it is following:
   In rules:

   array(
       'verifyCode',
       'captchaValid',
       'allowEmpty'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest || !CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),
       'enableClientValidation' => true,
       'message'=>Yii::t('app', 'wrong code'),
       'on' => array('create'),
   ),

Below:

```
public function captchaValid($field, $params) {
    if(!$this->hasErrors($field))
    {
        if (Yii::app()->params['testmode'] == true) // here is our mark
            return;
        $vc_key = "Yii.CCaptchaAction." . Yii::app()->getId() . ".site.captcha";
        if ( Yii::app()->session->get($vc_key) != $this->{$field} )
        {
            $this->addError($field, $params['message']);
        }

    }
}
```

That's all. For my case it was some additional completions, but in most of cases, approach above should work. If you will have some problems with it, let me know.